# Cant build APK on react native

Tags: android, react-native

im trying to signed apk with react native but i got some problem

Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.

> Failed to read key my-upload from store "D:\project\profile-muhammadiyah\android\app\my-upload-key.keystore": No key with alias 'my-upload' found in keystore D:\project\profile-muhammadiyah\android\app\my-upload-key.keystore

```
MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE=my-upload-key.keystore
MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS=my-upload
MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD=amicumss_
MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD=amicumss_
```

```
release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says what the problem is!
You have no key with alias 'my-upload' in your keystore

you should create it inside your keystore with running below [code in `command prompt` for windows](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android):

```
keytool -genkeypair -v -keystore my-upload-key.keystore -alias my-upload -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```